# Microsoft Lightswitch creating a dynamic user interface using c#, jquery mobile and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, css, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-lightswitch

So I am developing a Microsoft Lightswitch application using Visual Studio 2013 in c# and I need a dynamic UI.

Basically in the database I have a Person table, a Skill table and a PersonSkills table which links the two together (a person can have multiple skills and each skill has a skill level. Ignore the Person field for now - that will be taken out and done automatically).

[image: How it looks currently]

Now on the AddSkill page, I need to be able to add as many skills as I want without having to open the same AddSkill popup over and over again. How I did this currently is by (using google chrome) right-clicking on the + button to search for a skill and selecting Inspect Element, to view the css code of that button (because its a css/jquery mobile element).

This gave me the css code for that skill box and level box, and using the postRender method of lightswitch and the .change jquery method whenever the a skill is changed I add the code for another skill and level box to the component.

[image: Inspect element]

```
myapp.AddEditPersonSkill.left_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
// Write code here.
var context = $(element);

//Sorry that its all in one line and terrible...

context.change(function () {
    context.append('<div class="msls-first-column  msls-presenter msls-ctl-rows-layout msls-vauto msls-hstretch msls-presenter-content msls-font-style-normal msls-hscroll msls-label-host msls-rows-layout" style="min-width: 200px; max-width: 400px; width: 229px;"><div class="msls-clear msls-first-row  msls-presenter msls-ctl-details-modal-picker msls-vauto msls-hstretch msls-leaf"><div class="msls-label msls-label-align-top msls-clear msls-vauto"><label>Skill</label></div><div class="msls-clear msls-presenter-content msls-font-style-normal msls-vauto msls-hscroll"><div class="id-container"><form class="ui-listview-filter ui-bar-a ui-listview-filter-inset" role="search"><div class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-icon-searchfield ui-body-a ui-mini"><input placeholder="Search" data-type="search" class="ui-input-text ui-body-a"><a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-notext ui-input-clear-hidden" title="clear text" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a" data-mini="false"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">clear text</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a></div></form><ul class="id-auto-complete-element ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-theme="a" data-filter-placeholder="Search"></ul><a class="id-modal-button msls-has-search msls-large-icon ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-icon-notext" tabindex="0" data-role="button" data-icon="msls-add" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a" title=""><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-msls-add ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a></div><div class="id-auto-complete-dropdown"></div></div></div><div class="msls-clear msls-last-row  msls-presenter msls-ctl-text-box msls-vauto msls-hstretch msls-leaf msls-redraw"><div class="msls-label msls-label-align-top msls-clear msls-vauto"><label for="b8bfe3adf-Level" class="ui-input-text">Level</label></div><div class="msls-clear msls-presenter-content msls-font-style-normal msls-vauto msls-hscroll"><div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-a ui-mini"><input type="text" class="id-element ui-input-text ui-body-a" data-mini="true" maxlength="255" id="b8bfe3adf-Level"></div></div></div><div class="msls-clear"></div></div>');

});
```

};

[image: How it works currently]

Thats all fine and good - BUT, here is the problem: The new Skill box (that was just added to the screen) does not have a working button - the css/jquery mobile button does nothing. The first one still works fine but the new one is broken.

Is there a better way of doing this than what I am doing? Is there a built in lightswitch way of doing this?

EDIT: So it seems like the jquery button events are in a javascript file somewhere else, not within the button declaration itself:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-events.html

This means that even though I am creating the 'look and feel' of the buttons, they don't actually do anything yet. I have to figure out which method the buttons are calling and then use the .bind jquery method to bind the new buttons to the same method.

Comment: Can you clarify if the Skill records already exist and what you want is from the Person screen to associate existing Skills (creating new PersonSkill records) without opening the PersonSkill screen every time?

Comment: Yes, thats absolutely correct. The + button I am struggling with brings up a list of existing Skill records which are in stored in a different table (predictably, the Skills table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach to this could be to use a Popup defined on the Person screen (not the AddPersonSkills dialog).

On the ViewPerson screen:

1. In the "Popups" section of the screen designer, Add a new Popup
2. Add the PersonSkills query (if it isn't already there)
3. Drag the PersonSkills query to the position you want it to show on the screen
4. Just above the "PersonSkills" list you added, add a new button, specify the action to open the Popup you created
5. Add Data Item, choose "Query", choose "Skills"
6. Drag the "Skills" query onto the new Popup
7. Select the "Skills" List control that was added
8. In the "Actions" section of the property sheet, click on the link next to "Item Tap", choose to create a new method and insert the code below

```js
myapp.ViewPerson.Skills_ItemTap_execute = function(screen) {
  var personSkill = new myapp.PersonSkill();
  personSkill.Person = screen.Person;
  personSkill.Skill = screen.Skills.selectedItem;
  msls.application.applyChanges();
  screen.closePopup();
};
```

Here is what the experience ends up being like (in my example, I have Customers, Vendors and PreferredVendors as the relationship table (so Customers can have many PreferredVendors))

[image]

If you need to you can add more fields on the popup:

1. Add Data Item... --> Local Property (change type to integer), name it SkillLevelProp
2. Drag the SkillLevelProp property onto the Popup
3. Add a button to the Popup (choose Write my own method)
4. Move the code above from the Skills' tap to the new method for the button (we can't close the popup on tap anymore since the user will need to also set the SkillLevel)

```js
myapp.ViewPerson.submit_execute = function(screen) {
  var prefSkill = new myapp.PersonSkill();
  prefSkill.Person = screen.Person;
  prefSkill.Skill = screen.Skills.selectedItem;
  prefSkill.SkillLevel = screen.SkillLevelProp;
  msls.application.applyChanges();

  // clear out the SkillLevel value so it's empty the next time the popup is opened
  screen.SkillLevelProp = null;
  screen.closePopup();
};
```

This will make the popup look like this:

[image]

Here is what the design of the popup looks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I implemented this, and it works well when   I just want to add a skill to a person. However, a person also has a Skill level representing how good they are with that skill, and I don't see how this method will let the user select the skill and the either input or select a skill level. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, your method does not seem to be saving. I add the new personSkills (with a default Level of 0) to the person and when I try to navigate away from that person entity, it asks me to save the changes or discard them. When I click save the changes nothing happens... when I click on discard they are discarded and I can navigate away.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about SkillLevel.  I have edited my answer to account for this.  My example is saving the records, so not sure what is different with yours.  I will make my project available shortly so you can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You have really helped me so far - It works nicely for what I want to do - however I still cannot save it for some reason. When I click on my OK button the popup is closed, but when I try and navigate to a different screen i get the following popup: [link](http://i.imgur.com/OJnKGYQ.png), and if I do click on Save Changes then nothing happens - the data is not saved.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in PersonSkill_Inserting (use the "Add code" toolbar button from the Entity designer).  See if the breakpoint gets hit after applyChanges is called.  If it does get hit, change VS to break when CLR exceptions are thrown (CTRL + ALT + E gets you to the Exceptions window, check the Thrown column in the Common Language Runtime Exceptions row).

Comment: Thanks Dave, I found my problem. I modified my applyChanges() method to applyChanges().then(...) and passed it an error function - the error function got called in the end because I am trying to store an integer into the database field expecting a string. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As far as making your buttons work, did you use:

```
// Tell JQuery Moble to render
objFieldset.trigger("create");
```

See:
[JQuery Mobile Tree Using Collapsible Sections and Dynamic Views in LightSwitch](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2220/JQuery-Mobile-Tree-Using-Collapsible-Sections-and-Dynamic-Views-in-LightSwitch.aspx)